# YTM and YTC. how do you discount the coupon rate?

Tags: finance

A corporation sold a 30-year bond with a coupon rate of 8% (4% semiannually) two years ago. The bonds are callable at 105% of par value 5 years after issue and 103% of par value 10 years after issue. The bonds are currently priced at 120% of par value. Calculate the yield to call after 5 years, after 10 years, and the yield to maturity.

What I have done is for YTC5years, I discounted 40 using PV annuity formula using 6 periods + 1050/(1+i)^6 and got i=0.013, which gives YTC5years as 2.64%.  AM I on the right track?

If I am then I can do the rest. Thanks!

Comment: you discount using the yield rate

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you encounter the problem? Questions that consist only of a problem statement are discouraged on this site; you can improve the question at any time by editing it.

Comment: @whoopcrack, you are correct.  Look at the solution below

Answer (score 0):

I used goal seek in EXCEL to solve for yield to call 1, yield to call2 and yield to maturity.  Cells that are colored are the answers.
Goodluck

Satish

[image]